# Creating a javafx Image using an ArrayList of strings

Tags: java, image, javafx, arraylist

So i'm trying to create an Image object in javafx, but it doesn't seem to work with a list of strings, but it will with a single string. Here are my code examples:
This Code works just fine:

```
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("forest.png"); 
//forest.png is saved in my root directory which is why I don't need an absolute path
```

But for some reason this doesn't...:

```
ArrayList<String> pictures = new ArrayList<String>();
pictures.add("forset.png");
pictures.add("plains.png");
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(pictures.get(0)));
```

For the specific project I'm creating I'm going to have an X number of pictures that may be different every time, so I want to be able to save them into a List and just call the indexes of the List when I create the images. Please Help.

Comment: You've got a typo in there: Should be `forest.png`, not `forset.png` when adding to the list.

Comment: Haha thank you so much, sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes...